# OpenXML - Creating multiple pages based on a single template page

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I use Visual Studio to create programs, using WinForm and library OpenXML.
I have one Word template, one page; template.docx and I would like to generate a new Word document using the template.
How do I create different number of pages, where each page is the same (as the template)?

```
static void Create_NewWord()
{
   string documentFolder= @"C:\Users\name\Desktop\Open XML\EditWordFileUsingCsharp-main\SampleWordTemplate\{0}";
   FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(string.Format(documentFolder, "Template_label.docx"), FileMode.Open);
    
    using (MemoryStream memStr = new MemoryStream())
    {
        fileStream.CopyTo(memStr);
        fileStream.Close();
        
        using (WordprocessingDocument WPDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memStr, true))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating...");
            WordGenerator objWord = new WordGenerator(WPDoc);

            //Inserting text 
            objWord.UpdateTextoControlWord("Power", "417 W");
            objWord.UpdateTextoControlWord("Voltage", "230 V");

        }

        FileStream file = new FileStream(string.Format(documentFolder, "FinalWord.docx"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        memStr.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

I open Template_label.docx and change the text based on the TagName.

How to add another page, in the same newly generated FinalWord.docx file?